# Distance between 2 locations using STDistance

Tags: sql-server

I would like to find the nearest Employee for my Customer.

I have 2 tables

```
Customer_Master
Customer_ID  Customer_Name   Cust_Location
Cust100001   Subash          0xE6100000010C1B2E724F57172A408449F1F109685340
Cust100002   Naresh          0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8675340

Employee_Master
Emp_ID      Emp_name  Emp_Location
Emp100001   Prakash   0xE6100000010C363B527DE7172A4069C36169E0675340
Emp100002   Suresh    0xE6100000010C98C3EE3B86172A4064E597C118685340
Emp100003   Vincent   0xE6100000010CE5B8533A58172A4090DD054A0A685340
Emp100004   Paul      0xE6100000010C2EE6E786A6142A40A0A696ADF5675340
```

I have Location of the customer and also Employee. Now i want to select an employee who is nearest to the customer location.

I tried the below query which  is showing error

```
Select Emp_ID 
from Emp_Master 
where Emp_ID.Emp_Location.STDistance
(
    Select Cust_Location 
    from Cust_Master 
    where Cust_ID='Cust100001'
)
```

Comment: try it
Select Emp_ID from Emp_Master,Cust_Master
Where Emp_Master.Emp_Location == Cust_Matser.Cust_Location

Comment: Hi..AM getting the below error  "Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geography."

Comment: Your Locations are different types ?

Comment: the error indicates you have a `where` with no criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

```
USE Test;
GO

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Customers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CustomerName NVARCHAR(255)
    , LOC GEOMETRY
);

CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    ID INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Employees PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1)
    , EmployeeName NVARCHAR(255)
    , LOC GEOMETRY
);

TRUNCATE TABLE Customers;
TRUNCATE TABLE Employees;

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, LOC) VALUES ('Customer1',0xE6100000010C1B2E724F57172A408449F1F109685340);
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, LOC) VALUES ('Customer2',0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8675340);
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, LOC) VALUES ('Customer3',0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8675341);
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, LOC) VALUES ('Customer4',0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8675342);

INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeName, LOC) VALUES ('Employee1',0xE6100000010C1B2E724F57172A408449F1F109685340);
INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeName, LOC) VALUES ('Employee2',0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8775340);
INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeName, LOC) VALUES ('Employee3',0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8885341);
INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeName, LOC) VALUES ('Employee4',0xE6100000010CBE30992A18152A4093AAED26F8695342);

SELECT TOP(1) CustomerName, EmployeeName, Customers.LOC.STDistance(Employees.Loc) AS DistanceApart
FROM Customers, Employees
WHERE CustomerName = 'Customer2'
ORDER BY CustomerName, DistanceApart;
```

This returns the closest employee for the given customer.

Comment: Hi Vernon,Thank you for the suggestion. The Query is working with slight modifications. Actually the query you have suggested was returning customer insted of employee. So i have modified it ad its working fine now...

Answer (score 0):

I think the return measurement depends upon the Spatial Reference Identifiers (SRIDs) of your geography data type. The default is 4326 which is in meters. There' a table in the DB you can check Select * from sys.spatial_reference_systems

Comment: Hi Goyal..Yes 4326 is in meters. But the actual issue is the query itself is returning error in the syntax..